# How to add custom step or description to allure report using jamine/protractor

Tags: protractor, allure

I want add custom message or step or description in allure report, that how to achieve that.

Currently I am able to add screenshot `allure.createAttachment`, but if I use `allure.setDescription(description)` or `severity(severity)` or `createStep(name, stepFunc)`, nothing is showing in report.

Its not showing any error at the same time its not showing any content which I have added.

Answer (score 0):

Globally add `allure.addStep` in  `before: function() {}`

And you can call  `step("this is displayed in report:: ", //any driver functions());`